# COVID-19 Contact tracing- Is there any clarity on the duration of "contact"

Tags: covid-19, virus, sars-cov-2, united-states

I was somewhat surprised to hear that contract tracers are instructed to disregard contacts between an known infected person (positive tested) person and their contacts if the duration of a contact is less than 10 minutes (and distance is less than 6 feet)

Considering that the virus is capable of being transmitted by a simple handshake, and because a handshake only takes seconds, a restriction on time duration may be counter productive.*

The only CDC guidance I can find [here](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/php/public-health-recommendations.html) suggests the criteria should be <6ft for a "prolonged period of time", then goes on to say in a note: "Data are insufficient to precisely define the duration of time that constitutes a prolonged exposure. Recommendations vary on the length of time of exposure from 10 minutes or more to 30 minutes or more."

IMO, that does not appear to be a sound criteria (as to duration) to define a non-healthcare environment person-to-person contact with a known positive.

So my question is: Are there any other (new and improved???) CDC guidance documents that might alter that "prolonged contact" recommendation, perhaps even discussing the nature of the contact when less than 6 feet.

- counter productive in that it could impart a false sense of security, by not informing a contact that they were potentially exposed to a transmitter.

Note: Please migrate to Politics if that is a more appropriate site.

Comment: I think the premise of your question is false. As I read the guidance on the page you link that is only true if nothing occured that would point to increased risk. E.g. the page explicitly says that the type of interaction is important, so an interaction of few seconds with one coughing at someone else would be treated far more seriously than standing besides each other at the bus stop without any further happenings.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX, the question is really simple, Are there any updates to the CDC document that modify the" prolonged contact" recommendation?  How is that question "false"? If you believe that the "prolonged contact criteria" is modified, simply answer that by citing the modification.